# Send larger texts than 4kb/6kb in watson text to Speech

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

IBM Watson Text to Speech just allows to send 4kb in POST and 6kb in GET texts to synthesise . I'd like to send bigger files, is there any chance to do that, other than divide original text and combine final results.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid the current limitation. You need to split the text into smaller chunks.